# Cut rows into groups based on a factor column to calculate mean

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate a mean based on groupings in a factor row. Here is the code I have thus far:

```
exports_15E$Sv_Ln = 10^(exports_15E$Sv_mean/10) #converts logarithmic data to linear 
desiredGroupingUnit15E = cut(exports_15E$Date_time, breaks = "12 hour") #groups linear data into 12 hour time blocks from 6am to 6pm 
aggregate(exports_15E$Sv_Ln, by = list(desiredGroupingUnit15E), FUN = mean) #averages the data that has been grouped and saves it as a value
daily_avg_15E<- data.frame(aggregate(exports_15E$Sv_Ln, by = list(desiredGroupingUnit15E), FUN = mean)) #adds the grouped averaged value to the dataframe
daily_avg_15E$Sv_log = 10*log10(daily_avg_15E$x) #converts the nnewly averaged linear data back to logarithmic
daily_avg_15E$Date_POSIXct <- as.POSIXct(daily_avg_15E$Group.1, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="Asia/Bangkok") #renames and sets the column with dates and times to the preferred format
```

and a reprex example:

```
    Date_M     Time_M      Date_time    DayNight     Sv_Ln
 1 20211213 18:22:22 2021-12-13 18:22:00 Night    0.00000195
 2 20211213 19:22:23 2021-12-13 19:22:00 Night    0.00000266
 3 20211213 06:22:23 2021-12-13 06:22:00 Day      0.00000313
 4 20211213 07:22:23 2021-12-13 07:22:00 Day      0.00000526
 5 20211213 22:22:22 2021-12-13 22:22:00 Night    0.00000409
 6 20211213 23:22:22 2021-12-13 23:22:00 Night    0.00000658
 7 20211214 06:22:23 2021-12-14 06:22:00 Day      0.00000579
 8 20211214 07:22:22 2021-12-14 07:22:00 Day      0.00000724
 9 20211214 02:22:22 2021-12-14 02:22:00 Night    0.00000733
10 20211214 03:22:22 2021-12-14 03:22:00 Night    0.00000745
```

What I'm trying to do is get the mean for `Sv_Ln` based on the `DayNight` column. The issue is, just averaging by factor will give me 2 means. I'm trying to get the mean by groupings of `DayNight` rows. So the first 2 rows will be averaged, then the next two and so on. The reason I haven't just used 'cut' is because these `dayNight` groups aren't consistent in number (in the real data set, they are 12 rows long maximum). I'm trying to just get a mean for each group without averaging everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
dt <- read.table(text ="Date_M     Time_M      Date_time T    DayNight     Sv_Ln
1 20211213 18:22:22 2021-12-13 18:22:00 Night    0.00000195
2 20211213 19:22:23 2021-12-13 19:22:00 Night    0.00000266
3 20211213 06:22:23 2021-12-13 06:22:00 Day      0.00000313
4 20211213 07:22:23 2021-12-13 07:22:00 Day      0.00000526
5 20211213 22:22:22 2021-12-13 22:22:00 Night    0.00000409
6 20211213 23:22:22 2021-12-13 23:22:00 Night    0.00000658
7 20211214 06:22:23 2021-12-14 06:22:00 Day      0.00000579
8 20211214 07:22:22 2021-12-14 07:22:00 Day      0.00000724
9 20211214 02:22:22 2021-12-14 02:22:00 Night    0.00000733
10 20211214 03:22:22 2021-12-14 03:22:00 Night    0.00000745",
           header = TRUE)

library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
dt[, groupid := rleid(DayNight)]
dt[, .(avg = mean(Sv_Ln)), by = .(DayNight, groupid)]
```